# How to prevent d3-brush from adding "display:none" to .selection and .handle onmousedown

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

I recently noticed that after brushing an area using d3-brush, if you click within the brush's extent outside of the selection, the selection becomes invisible. Closer inspection revealed that the svg `rect` elements `.selection`and `.handle` are given a `display: none` property, probably in response to a `mousedown` event.

This [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1xtftq3/1/) is a minimal example of this behaviour. Drag to select within the white area, then click the white area outside of your selection.

Edit: As Ivan brought up in the comments, this seems to be the default behaviour for empty selections.

How can I prevent it? I tried simply adding an empty `mousedown` event listener to `.overlay`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: When you click on white space new empty selection was created. It isn't bug. This behavior is normally.

Comment: Ok! I didn't know empty selections had `display: none` by default, but it makes sense now that I think about it. Still, how can I prevent the default behaviour then?